# two for loops in batch to take data from two different text files

Tags: for-loop, batch-file

I'm trying to create a small script that will create a folder for each user name from a text file (`Users.txt`) and within that folder it'll create another subfolder with their ID's (`ID.txt`)

I've created the following script:

```
@echo off


setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set Users=Users.txt
set ID=id.txt

for /f %%i IN (%Users%) DO ((
    set username=%%i
    )       
    for /f %%j IN (%ID%) DO (
    set ID=%%j
    mkdir c:\Test\!username!\!ID!       
)
)
```

but the result is that for each 'user' folder I got all the ID's subfolders.

Comment: What format is the data in, i.e. how is users.txt and id.txt structured?

Comment: Hey Jeroenh, Thanks for your fast reply! each line = user in the users.txt, same happening for the ID.txt, each ID is seperated by a simple 'Enter'

Comment: so how do you link the users with their IDs?

Comment: they are sorted in the same order, the first ID in the ID.txt is for the first user in the Users.txt, and so on.. so lets say i have 10 rows of users and 10 rows of ID's, the 5th ID in the ID.txt belongs to the 5th user in the Users.txt file.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming both files have the same number of lines:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set "userFile=Users.txt"
set "idFile=id.txt"
<"%idFile%" (
  for "usebackq" /f %%i IN ("%userFile%") do (
    set /p "id="
    mkdir "c:\Test\%%i\!id!"
  )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comments, you could keep a counter of sorts, and in your nested loop look up the correct ID based on that counter. I'm not even sure that is possible though.

Something like this maybe (untested):

```
set COUNTER = 0
for /f %%i in (%users%) do (
    set /A COUNTER = %COUNTER%+1
    goto :callInnerLoop %%i %COUNTER%
)

goto :EOF
:callInnerLoop
SET LOCALCOUNTER=0
for /f %%i in (%id%) DO (
   set /A COUNT=%COUNT%+1
   if (!COUNT!=%2) (
      REM FOUND %ID%
      goto :EOF
   )   
)
```

This is really messy code though, a batch script hardly seems the right tool for the job. It would become a lot easier if you can get the files merged (e.g. a CSV file with 'USERNAME;ID' on each line). Otherwise I would recommend to switch to a more powerful scripting language like powershell.

Answer (score 0):

One pretty ugly way; read the usernames then fetch the corresponding line from the id file

```
@echo off
setlocal disabledelayedexpansion
set Users=Users.txt
set ID=id.txt
set linenum=0

for /f %%i IN (%Users%) DO (
  call :getId %%linenum%% %%i
  set /a linenum=linenum+1  
)
goto :eof
:getId
if "%1"=="0" (set options=) else set options=skip=%1
for /f "%options%" %%j in (%id%) do (
    echo %2\%%j
    goto:eof
 )
```